# Phase transition in 3+1 abelian theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, phase-transition, confinement

In historical paper [A View From the Island](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9211140), A. M. Polyakov wrote at 6th page:

> In the **abelian case**, these
>   dislocations turned to be just the world lines of magnetic monopoles and I predicted
>   the **phase transition leading to confinement** (in 3 + 1 case).

What did he mean? Does it mean, that exist phase on abelian theory (pure theory or theory with matter?), where elementary excitations are gluebal-like objects? What is mechanism lying behind this phenomena?

Comment: This phenomenon and the explicit model are discussed in detail in Polyakov's tetbook, *Gauge Fields and Strings*, as well as the original reference, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269375901628?via%3Dihub 
Closely related questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202626/compact-qed-and-non-compact-qed-polyakov-textbook
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466578/compact-qed-in-different-dimensions?noredirect=1&lq=1