# Gauge theory of non-abelian 2-form

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, action

It's continuation of question: [Abelian theory with confiment in 4d (Polyakov book)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545951/abelian-theory-with-confiment-in-4d-polyakov-book)

1. It's quite simple to construct theory of **abelian 2-form** with gauge transformation:
   $$
   A_{[\mu\nu]} \to  A_{[\mu\nu]} + \partial_{[\mu}\alpha_{\nu]}
   $$
   Or in form language ($A=A_{[\mu\nu]}dx^\mu dx^\nu $ is two form):
   $$
   A\to A +d\alpha
   $$
   Field strength:
   $$
   F_{[\mu\nu\rho]} = \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu\rho]}
   $$
   $$
   F=dA
   $$
   $$
   S = \int d^4x \;F\wedge\star F = \int d^4x \;F^{[\mu\nu\rho]}F_{[\mu\nu\rho]}
   $$
2. How to generalize this to **non-abelian 2-form**?

It is not clear even how define non-abelian transformation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-form_electrodynamics#Non-abelian_generalization

Comment: @bolbteppa, thank you! Do you know some introduction to this ideas for physicist?

Comment: I found https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/string/archives/000766.html some interesting text about it, but it doesn't contain enough details.

Comment: @bolbteppa  The question is about non-abelian generalizations.  That link only discusses abelian forms.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely open, in the sense that there are multiple proposals for non-abelian 2-forms (and also, for higher forms).

One I like (that is not mine...) is the relatively early proposal of C. Hofman *[Nonabelian 2-forms](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207017)*. That paper is fairly self-contained too.