# What book do I read to study QED

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, education

Assuming I understand quantum mechanics, what is a good book to study on QED? Enough to get me to understanding it at a graduate physics level.

Comment: Do you already know the basics of quantum field theory? If not, you'll probably want to start there. Check the [overarching books question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/168783) for many reference suggestions on QFT

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274338/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A common pedagogical approach is to first learn the quantum field theory of scalar fields *before* learning the quantum field theory of spinor and vector fields. Scalar fields are considerably simpler, and the essence of QFT will be clearer with them.